# How to improve skills while unemployed?

Tags: job-search, career-development

What would you suggest for me to improve changes to get a job. I'm physically handicapped man from Finland who has a university education. But as there is so much unemployment, I haven't got a job although I have tried to hard to get one.

Should I just study more and more courses on my major subject on university or start writing blog/homepage/Wikipedia on things I know or start to study some totally new field?

So how can I stay active when unemployed?

Comment: Be positive and optimist. What do you want to achieve? Did you consider going out to work in other countries?

Comment: I would like to be useful for someone. There was a job where I was forced to use some software but I like more jobs where I have been given a task and I can use the best possible methods, software etc I know to solve the problem.

Working abroad is an option but on my work experience it would be hard to find a job abroad as I have not too much job experience I have managed to do well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things I do is aggressively leverage community forums.  While I think StackExchange attracts a pretty high caliber of individual, I've gotten a lot more contact from spamming posts with comments on LinkedIn.  This:

1. Gets your name out.
2. Promotes personally awareness of business practices.
3. Provides insight into industry trends.
4. Forces you to network.
5. Provides direction for enrichment opportunities.

Without knowing more about your situation than that I wouldn't target anything in particular.  When I was last looking for a job I tried sending out about 100 applications a month (each with custom cover letter) and being sure to do follow-up on those.  People don't seem to hire from applications anymore (networks only) but everyone once in a while you'll find an actual opening and at least get to make a new contact.

Haven't tried the blog yet but it's probably not a bad idea.

Comment: I would concur that online communities are a way to sharpen soft skills and get started on networking.